# Unable to solve webdriver error in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, nunit

Two testcases are executed in this when the first one runs but when the second runs error is thrown the same is mentioned in the image.
Why this is happening? I'm unable to solve this error.. Please help!

[image: Error]

```
[TestFixture]
public  class ListScenarios : ExtentManager
{
    #region "Variables"
    IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    int rowNumber;
    #endregion

    [OneTimeSetUp]
   public void Setup()
    {
                 
       Thread.Sleep(4000);
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://");
    }
      
    [Test,Order(1)]
  
    public void AdminView()
    {
        rowNumber = 1;
        ExcelReader.PopulateInCollection(@"TestSheet.xlsx");
        test = report.CreateTest("Testcase one");
 
    }

    [Test,Order(2)]
    
    public void ViewSlist()
    {

        rowNumber = 2;
        ExcelReader.PopulateInCollection(@"TestSheet.xlsx");
        test = report.CreateTest("Testcase two");

        
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        if (!(webDriver.PageSource.Contains("Update")) && !(webDriver.PageSource.Contains("Unlock")))
        {
            test.Log(Status.Pass, "validated");

        }
        else
        {
            
            test.Log(Status.Fail, "Validations didnot verified");

        }
    }
```

Comment: According to this error you're using remote webdriver server and it failed to connect. Have you started the webdriver server?

Comment: @derloopkat That should nail the OP

Comment: what can be the other way to generate extent report for multiple testcases report?Does nunit support any other way for generating report?